# How to launch master_sync_fkie from the launch file?

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Multimaster FKIE package provides this node `master_sync` that sets topics to synchronize among multiple ROS masters. When I launch it from the terminal, I use command

```
rosrun master_sync_fkie master_sync _ignore_nodes:=[/gazebo*,/gazebo_gui*,/panda*]
```

so I'm passing this list to it. Now if I want to launch it from launch file, I would need to launch the node like this

```
<node name="my_master_sync_fkie" pkg="master_sync_fkie" type="master_sync" ... />
```

and then somehow put those list arguments to it. How can I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323550/how-to-launch-master_sync_fkie-from-the-launch-file?/) by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 308 on 2019-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> When I launch it from the terminal, I use command

> ```
> rosrun master_sync_fkie master_sync _ignore_nodes:=[/gazebo*,/gazebo_gui*,/panda*]
> ```

`ignore_nodes` here is a *private parameter* of `master_sync`. The ROS wiki for the package `master_sync_fkie` documents those [here](http://wiki.ros.org/master_sync_fkie?distro=melodic#Interface). The specific `rosrun` command line syntax you're using is documented [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server#Private_Parameters).

Private parameters can be passed to `node`s in `.launch` files by adding a [rosparam](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam) or [param](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param) element as a child of the [node](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node) element.

For the specific `rosrun` command line you show, that would look something like this:

```
<node name="my_master_sync_fkie" pkg="master_sync_fkie" type="master_sync">
  <rosparam>
    ignore_nodes:
      - '/gazebo*'
      - '/gazebo_gui*'
      - '/panda*'
  </rosparam>
</node>
```

Note that I used the "verbose list" form here, which I happen to like. You can also still use the single-line notation you used with `rosrun`.

Note also: the single quotes (`'`) are probably not necessary, but when strings contain (what appear to be) globbing characters I'm always a bit careful and just wrap them in quotes.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1